# Why is my output undefined?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, undefined

I write a Quiz in Javascript and HTML. For a statistic I want create a table with the questions, user answers and the correct answers.

Is there a multiple choice answer for a question I get a undefined as output instead the user's answers.

Why I get undefined output by multiple choice answers? Questions with one answer works perfect.

**My code:**

```
$(function() {

  var quiz = [];
  var items = localStorage.getObject('tipkit');

  $.getJSON('api/quiz.json', function(data) {
    $.each(data.questions, function(i, f) {
      var tblRow = 
        "<tr>" + 
          // question id
          "<td>" + f.id + "</td>" +
          // question
          "<td>" + f.question + "</td>" +
          //user answers (id's and text)
          "<td>" + items['quest' + f.id] + ": " + f.answers[items['quest'+f.id]] + "</td>" + 
          //correct answers (id's and text)
          "<td>" + f.correct + ": " + f.answers[f.correct] + "</td>" + 
        "</tr>";
      $(tblRow).appendTo(".table tbody");
    });
  });

});
```

**api.json**

```
{
  "questions": [
    {
      "question":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit?",
      "linktitle":"Lorem ipsum",
      "id":1,
      "correct":"0",
      "type":"radio",
      "answers": [
        "Amet Commodo Magna Euismod",
        "Venenatis Euismod Commodo",
        "Bibendum Ullamcorper Ornare Vehicula Commodo",
        "Ipsum Fusce Sem Venenatis"
      ]
    },
    {
      "question":"Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et?",
      "id":"2",
      "correct":"1, 3",
      "type":"checkbox",
      "answers": [
        "Dapibus Dolor Sem Egestas",
        "Vehicula Amet Parturient",
        "Commodo Parturient",
        "Tellus Dolor Ridiculus Etiam"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

**localstorage**

```
key: tipkit
value: {"quest1":["1"], "quest2":["2","3"]}
```

Comment: add json returned from api and what is data stored in localstorage

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam in the json file are the questions and in the localstorage I save the answers from the user

Comment: i understand that but i need to see the json file structure

Comment: @FadiAboMsalam sry, I've edited my question

Comment: @Mr.Dev did you checked my answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
"correct":"1, 3"
```

this line is creating problem. As `"1,3"` won't resolve to a index for `answers` array. that's why `f.answers[f.correct]` returns `undefined`.

You can use this method to get multiple answers:

```
function getMultipleAnswers(answers, indexes)
{
    var selectedAnswers = new Array();
        var indexe_array = indexes.split(',');
    for(var i = 0; i < indexe_array.length; i++)
    {
      selectedAnswers.push(answers[indexe_array[i]]);
    }
    return selectedAnswers;
}
```

Comment: It works for the correct answers column but not for the user answers column. I get a error: Uncaught TypeError: indexes.split is not a function

Answer (score 0):

**Note :**

When we are going to store a JavaScript object in to `HTML5 localStorage`, It will convert the `JSON object` in to a `JSON string`.

```js
var jsonObj = {"quest1":["1"], "quest2":["2","3"]};

console.log('typeof jsonObj: ' + typeof jsonObj);

// Put the object into storage
localStorage.setItem('tipkit', jsonObj);

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('tipkit');

console.log('typeof retrievedObject: ' + typeof retrievedObject);
```

**Solution :**

We have to `stringify` our JSON object before storing it, and later `parse` it while retrieving.

**DEMO**

```js
var jsonObj = {"quest1":["1"], "quest2":["2","3"]};

console.log('typeof jsonObj: ' + typeof jsonObj);

// Put the stringify object into storage
localStorage.setItem('tipkit', JSON.stringify(jsonObj));

// Retrieve the object from storage
var retrievedObject = localStorage.getItem('tipkit');

console.log('typeof retrievedObject: ' + typeof retrievedObject);

// Parse the JSON String.
console.log(JSON.parse(retrievedObject));
```

Comment: I stringify and parse it but the output is the same

Comment: You can check the code snippet in my answer. It is working as per your expectation.

Comment: var items is now: var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('tipkit')); and   I save the answers in the local Storage with this line localStorage.setItem('tipkit', JSON.stringify(items));  I get the same output like before the changes

Comment: Can you please provide the plnkr url so that i can look into your code.